# extruded curves changing orientation on render

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

I've followed the usual steps to extrude a curve upon a path. All looks well in the viewport.

[image]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5iqnmbl5p0a87a/Screenshot%202015-12-14%2015.32.11.png?dl=0

Upon render, I find the orientation and position significantly changed. This mystifies me. What calculations change between preview and render? And what am I doing wrong?

[image]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d49z5jx12vlmuub/Screenshot%202015-12-14%2015.32.33.png?dl=0

Any advice or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lfvtda17fttrj7v/loco.blend?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to SE. In the future please link the images directly into the post and use. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to host your files. The problem with external links is that if they change or disappear the question will not make much sense to future users. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks cegaton. I attempted to use markdown and straight html but was foiled. I presumed my images were too large. Thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (or more) of your modifiers is disabled for rendering:

[image]

Enable it and render happily ever after.

[image]

The camera icon toggles the use of the modifier for rendering.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! - I'm assuming that since it was referencing a curve for another object (an unfortunate breadcrumb trail from prior methods attempted), it was throwing a conflict and screwing up the orientation. Clearly I didn't think to check there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please know that the User View and Camera View are different.  Press 0 (zero on numeric keypad) repeatedly to switch between the two views.

As well objects can be visible or invisible during editing versus render mode.  The outliner window has eye icons and camera icons to control this.

Comment: Understood - but results are the same.